# Is it possible to add strings that differ by case to CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton?

Tags: c++, mfc

MSDN appears to be wrong
[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctoolbarcomboboxbutton-class?view=msvc-160)

> `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton::AddItem`
> ...If the item text is already in the list box, the new data is stored with the existing item. The search for the item is case sensitive.

However `AddItem` calls into `FindItem` to prevent duplication

```
int CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton::FindItem(LPCTSTR lpszText) const
{
ENSURE(lpszText != NULL);

int iIndex = 0;
for (POSITION pos = m_lstItems.GetHeadPosition(); pos != NULL; iIndex++)
{
    if (m_lstItems.GetNext(pos).CompareNoCase(lpszText) == 0) <-- gets rejected as duplicate
    {
        return iIndex;
```

`FindItem` isn't virtual so I can't override it.
Any workarounds?

Comment: What happens if you do override `FindItem`? The `AddItem` member *is* virtual, so that should call the override, maybe.

Comment: ... of course, you would need to have overridden `AddItem` for your derived class (and possibly any other members that call the base-class `FindItem`).

Comment: The combo box control was historically used primarily for file names. It looks like it inherited Windows' filesystem semantics (case-preserving, but case-insensitive). A workaround would not only need to change the `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`, but also the `CComboBox` it contains, including its `FindStringExact` member (which, incidentally, isn't really *that* exact; it, too, is case-insensitive). I don't see an easy way to force case-sensitivity into the existing implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - yes @Adrian Mole AddItem is virtual, no overriding it didn't work! IInspectable may be onto something with underlying behaviour. Ah well.